# Warning: Unexpected response status when fetching server time: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window':

Tags: prometheus

Warning: Unexpected response status when fetching server time: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials: /api/v1/query?query=time()

I am just getting started with prometheus and While using prometheus UI i am getting the above error.
How can i sole this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.